# Haskell Type issue

Tags: haskell

I wrote the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module MonoidApp where

class Monoid' a where 
    mempty'  :: a
    mappend' :: a -> a -> a

    mconcat' :: [a] -> a
    mconcat' = foldr mappend' mempty'

instance Monoid' Int where 
    mempty' :: Int a => a
    mempty' = 0

    mappend' :: Int a => a -> a -> a
    mappend' a b = (+) a b
```

But it runs into error:

```
‘Int’ is applied to too many type arguments
    In the type signature for ‘mempty'’: mempty' :: Int a => a
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid' Int’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `Int` is a type with no parameters, but you've tried to apply it to one. I'm guessing you actually mean `mempty' :: Int; mappend' :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

Comment: What if you leave out lines `mempty' :: Int a => a` and `mappend' :: Int a => a -> a -> a`?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Then I cannot use the function with parameter (`mappend' 1 2`): _No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘it’_

Comment: I need to a type every time to make it work: `mappend' (1::Int) (2::Int)`

Comment: Or I can change a type of instance to `instance Monoid' Integer where `.

Comment: But I want to specify a type of functions explicitly: 'mempty' :: Int a => a' in instance.

Comment: Don't change your question in a way that doesn't include your original problem. If you have additional information add an update section, if you have new questions open a separate question.

Comment: @barbara But what you say you are trying to specify fundamentally doesn't make sense (or at the very least, it isn't Haskell). The type `Int a => a` doesn't mean anything at all - it simply isn't a valid type. It looks like you are writing `mappend' 1 2` and getting an error. This is a valid expression, whose type is `(Num a, Monoid' a) => a`. You *must* specify the type manually every time - since you can have `mappend' 1 2 :: Int` or `:: Integer` or basically anything else. Since type classes are open, the compiler can't assume that that the `1` is an `Int` just because it could be an `Int`.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
instance Monoid' Int where
    mempty' :: Int
    mempty' = 0

    mappend' :: Int -> Int -> Int
    mappend' a b = (+) a b
```